# Running batch which call PowerShell which return value script in CMD. No output from PowerShell script in console

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

When getting returned value from .ps1 script in a `for` loop I don't see `Write-Output` and `Write-Host` results.
When I execute the PowersShell script normally the output is present in console but I can't get returned value.
Is any solution for that?

```batch
echo off
echo BATCH
powershell -Command .\ps_for_batch.ps1
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command "& {.\ps_for_batch.ps1; exit $LastExitCode}"') do set "var=%%a"
echo var: %var%
echo END
```

`ps_for_batch.ps1`:

```bsh
Write-Output "This is PowerShell Write-Output"
Write-Host 'This is PowerShell Write-Host'
$temp = Read-Host 'This is PowerShell Read-Host'
return $temp
```

Result in console:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>echo off
BATCH
This is PowerShell Write-Output
This is PowerShell Write-Host
This is PowerShell Read-Host: input
input
This is PowerShell Read-Host: input
var: input
END
```

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Of course you can't see the output, the `for /f` consumes it and sets it to the environment variable `var` overwriting previous content with every new line.